# How to print multiple pages in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0

How to print multiple pages in silverlight.
Actually I have a scenario in silverlight and I have the button click event where I am able to print all the contents in the single page and all the excess content is been removed but Im not getting the next page print

This is my button click event

```
private void btnSubmitPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                _currentIndex = 0;

                 PrintDocument docprin = new PrintDocument();

                 docprin.PrintPage += new EventHandler<PrintPageEventArgs>(docprin_PrintPage);

                  string DocumentName = "Balaji";

                    docprin.Print(DocumentName);

             }

    //I Combine all the List into to a single string by using Linq

             void docprin_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
            {
                string delimeter = "\n";

                    var checkval = ListOfPageComments.Select(i => i.Comment.Insert(100, Environment.NewLine));//This lINQ OPERATION
               var ListofPagecommentsAscending = from n in ListOfPageComments orderby n.Date descending select n;

     var CommentsLineBreaks = ListofPagecommentsAscending.Select(conmmentss =>
                   {
                       var retur = conmmentss;
                       if (conmmentss.Comment.Length > 100)
                       {
                           IEnumerable<string> spllitingvaluetoNewLine = (Enumerable.Range(0, conmmentss.Comment.Length / 100).Select(j => conmmentss.Comment.Substring(j * 100, 100)));
                           string RejoiningLinestoSingle = String.Join(" \n ", spllitingvaluetoNewLine);
                           conmmentss.Comment = RejoiningLinestoSingle;
                           return conmmentss;
                       }
                       return conmmentss;
                   });

               var delimitedcomments = CommentsLineBreaks.Select(i => i.Date + "\n" + i.Comment).Aggregate((i, j) => i + delimeter + j);

                string Printcomments = String.Join(delimeter, delimitedcomments);


              List<string> get = (Enumerable.Range(0, Printcomments.Length / 800).Select(j => Printcomments.Substring(j * 800, 800))).ToList();


//AFTER GETTING THE VALUE OF STRING I SPLIT THEM INTO A LIST 
                while (_currentIndex < get.Count())//lOOPING CONDITION TO PRINT MULTIPLE PAGES
                {
                    var pageRoot = new Canvas();
                    e.PageVisual = pageRoot;

                    _currentTop = PAGEMARGIN;
                    _availableSpace = e.PrintableArea.Height - PAGEMARGIN * 2;


                  //  var txt = new TextBlock { Text = Printcomments };

                    var txt = new TextBlock { Text = get[_currentIndex].ToString() };


                    if (ROWHEIGHT > _availableSpace)
                    {

                        e.HasMorePages = true;
                        break;


                    }


                    txt.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, _currentTop);
                    txt.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, PAGEMARGIN);


                    _currentTop += ROWHEIGHT;
                    _availableSpace -= ROWHEIGHT;
                    pageRoot.Children.Add(txt);
                    _currentIndex++;

                }

           }
```

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-rough-notes-printing.aspx) and [here](http://gruchalski.com/2009/11/20/printing-data-on-multiple-pages-with-silverlight-4/) are two blog posts that describe multipage printing for Silverlight in more detail.